# Convert 3 two dimensional arrays to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 two dimensional arrays all have the following shape.

> (1, 4339)

They're called:

array1

array2

array3

How do I put them into a dataframe so I have the following format:

[image: expected dataframe]

I thought something like the following would work:

```
df = pd.concat([array1, array2, array3], axis=1)
```

But I get the following error message:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ""; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel
>   (deprecated) objs are valid

Comment: Try to use dictionary like {'array1':array1, 'array2':array2,'array3':array3} and then initialize dataframe with dict...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":arr1.reshape(4339),"b":arr2.reshape(4339),"c":arr3.reshape(4339)})
```

You can use this.

Answer (score 0):

As said by others, do it with constructing a dataframe from scratch.

One issue is the shape of your original arrays, see what happens if you make `pd.Series(array1)` on your original data.

Here is something that you could use a basis for making a function for reuse…

```
a = np.arange(5).reshape((1,5))
pd.DataFrame({k: a.flatten() for k, a in zip('abc', (a, a, a))})
```